# Tex-shell in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

Whenever I compile a file in AUCTeX (e.g. `C-c` `C-c` and then choosing an option) , it creates a buffer `tex-shell` where I can see the output of the compilation command. Once the compilation finishes this shell buffer stays open. What is the right way to close it?

Besides showing me the compilation output, what else can I use it for?

Answer (score 3):

When an Emacs window is split into two (or more parts), the command `delete-other-windows` will close the subwindows keeping only the one with the focus. The command is bound to

```
C-x 1
```